# To execute a task file from a role in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have setup basic directory architecture for my ansible playbooks.
I have defined two roles:-
1) www:-To manage all the site deployment
2) root :- To do the root related tasks

My root roles contains following tasks:-
1) Setup a new site on target server
2) Start the web server (apache,nginx)

I want to restart my apache server after the site deployment and for that i have created a playbook called apache-restart under tasks for the root roles.This is how my directory structure looks like

[image]

This is what i am trying in my site.yml

```
---

- name: Deploy Application
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  roles: 
    - www
  become: true
  become_user: www-data
  tags: 
    - site-deployment


- name: Restart Apache Server
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  roles: 
    - root
  tasks: 
    include: roles/root/apache-restart.yml
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tags: 
    - site-deployment
```

When i am running this playbook it throwing me this error:-

```
ERROR! A malformed block was encountered.

The error appears to have been in '/Users/Atul/Workplace/infra-automation/deployments/LAMP/site.yml': line 18, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Restart Apache Server
  ^ here
```

is there any better way so that i can directly inclue apache-restart.yml file with my site.yml by specifying **root** role because if i include only role then ansible will start looking for main.yml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tasks` should be a list, so:

```
tasks: 
  - include: roles/root/apache-restart.yml
```

Comment: If i don't want to specify the file directly just want to include apache-restart as i have already mentioned the role can i also do that??

Comment: You included code and an error message, so I wrote an answer how to fix it. If you wanted to ask for something different, why do you include bad code along with the message?

Comment: Ohh..sorry I just want to use apache-restart file from root role with out specifying the path..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I want to use a task from apache-restart.yml file and to do that i have mentioned the role where ansible needs to find that file

Comment: I have tried with include_role..but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Rename `apache-restart.yml` to `main.yml` in `root/tasks` directory and the tasks specified in that file will be automatically run when you call `root` role

After renaming the file you can simplify `Restart apache server` play to

```
- name: Restart Apache Server
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  roles: 
    - root
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tags: 
    - site-deployment
```

Ansible best practice to conditionally restart a server or a daemon is to use [handlers](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#task-and-handler-organization-for-a-role)

In your case you'd create a handler called `Restart Apache Server` in `www` role and notify it in relevant tasks in that role. Using the restart handler in `www` you can get rid of `root` role altogether.

Comment: I couldn't do that because i also wants to create new sites from same role

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Can you please clarify exactly what you try to achieve and add the contents of apache-restart.yml and www/tasks/main.yml to your question.